# Can we copy content of old YAML to new YAML without using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml

Referring to discussion on "Copy content from one YAML to another YAML after comparison of keys" ([Copy content from one YAML to another YAML after comparison of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661712/copy-content-from-one-yaml-to-another-yaml-after-comparison-of-keys))

Is there any way to do this without using ruamel.yaml module. Since I'm using Python 2.7.5, that module is not available.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7.5

import os.path
import yaml
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
```

Error faced: -

```
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml
```

Thanks,

Comment: ruamel.yaml, although not tested on 2.7.5 specifically, runs with any of the 2.7 series. What is your problem using it? An example of what you tried (and what doesn't work) should be included in this question.

Comment: I tested that with py2.7.5 already. Got issue as shown above. That's why I need to know whether we can copy content of old YAML to new YAML without using ruamel.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply alter the given code to `import yaml` instead of `ruamel.yaml`. You wouldn't have `round_trip_load` and `round_trip_dump`, but you can use `safe_load` and `safe_dump` instead. This will not keep comments since that is a ruamel feature.

Comment: Yeah, seems its working with that command, but then can it preserve the format of the YAML file? Seems it arrange that in ascending order.
So, based on your statement, without ruamel, there is no other ways to keep the comment?

Comment: There is, but you'd need to implement it yourself. For example, you can use PyYaml's low-level [Events](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#events) API; each event has a `start_mark` and an `end_mark` which you can use as offset on the input stream to recognise skipped parts which are probably comments or indentation. If you query an event stream from PyYaml's parser, you can then – instead of rendering the events again – copy the parts surrounding the events you're interested in from the input stream. This is obviously not trivial and probably more work than you'd want to put into it.

Comment: I see. Good recommendation. I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is not with ruamel.yaml not being available for Python 2.7.5, but with something being wrong with your environment (actual Python configuration, version of pip, your platform). `ruamel.yaml` works perfectly fine with 2.7.5, as the following shows:

```
$ virtualenv -p /opt/python/2.7.5/bin/python /tmp/so_47987860
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python/2.7.5/bin/python
New python executable in /tmp/so_47987860/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source /tmp/so_47987860/bin/activate
(so_47987860) $ python --version
Python 2.7.5
(so_47987860) $ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /tmp/so_47987860/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
(so_47987860) $ pip install ruamel.yaml
Collecting ruamel.yaml
/tmp/so_47987860/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/tmp/so_47987860/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading ruamel.yaml-0.15.35-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (534kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 542kB 1.5MB/s 
Collecting ruamel.ordereddict; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version <= "2.7" (from ruamel.yaml)
  Using cached ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: ruamel.ordereddict, ruamel.yaml
Successfully installed ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.13 ruamel.yaml-0.15.35
(so_47987860) $ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Dec 29 2017, 09:46:55) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ruamel.yaml
>>> yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
>>> import sys
>>> yaml.dump(dict(working_normal='2.7.5'), sys.stdout)
working_normal: 2.7.5
>>> exit()
(so_47987860) $ deactivate
$
```

Since you are using an outdated version of Python, you should check if you are not  using an outdated version of `pip` with that. Old versions of `pip` are known to have caused problems.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. After run this command (pip --version), seems that file is not exist in my /usr/bin directory. Will try to get this install first and rerun that.